# Команда для получения атрибутов файла

Tags: windows, файлы, cmd

нужно переименовать файлы (музыка) в цикле, в соответствии с их атрибутами (номер, название, исполнитель, альбом).

какие команды использовать, чтобы получить все эти и другие атрибуты?

Comment: Интересует результат или процесс? Если результат, то нужно взять специально обученную программу (например, Mp3Tag) и не придумывать уже придуманное.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под атрибутами: mp3-таг или же указанные параметры (номер, название и т.д.) находятся в имени файла и их нужно внедрить в аудио как таги? Командная строка не располагает средствами манипуляции mp3-тагами, так что вам скорее придется смотреть в сторону WSH или использовать сторонние утилиты.

Comment: @Эникейщик, результат

Comment: @gregzakharov, указанные параметры

Comment: У Total Commander есть очень удобная команда `Files / Multi-Rename`. Позволяет как угодно преобразовать имена группы файлов.

Comment: @freim, да? не знал, спасибо. дома попробую

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть скрипт для подобной задачи на Powershell. Автор - не я, не знаю имени автора. Но он работает, плюс содержит подробные комментарии для понимания. Вот он:

```
#    Массовое переименование MP3-файлов
#
#.Параметры
#    Ren_Mp3_Files.ps1 <Path_2_Folder_containing_MP3_Files>
#
#    Path_2_Folder_containing_MP3_Files - путь к папке, содержащей MP3-файлы
#
#
#.Пример запуска: 
#     .\Ren_Mp3_Files.ps1 "C:\mp3\Beatles"
#
#    Новые имена файлов будут сформированы по следующему шаблону:
#         <Название_альбома>--<Номер_трека>--<Название_композиции>
#
#    (информацию о названиях альбома, трека, авторе и т.п. берем из расширенных свойств файла, 
#     доступных при использовании COM-объекта Shell.Application)
#############################################################################################
#
param($Path2mp3Folder = $(throw "В качестве параметра запуска укажите в двойных кавычках путь к паке, содержащей mp3-файлы!"))
#$Path2mp3Folder -путь к папке, в которой лежат файлы mp3, подлежащие переименованию
#
cls
#
#Удаляем оконечный слэш, если таковой был указан,
#чтобы в дальнейшем логика работы программы не зависела о того,
#был ли указан оконечный слэш в пути к целевой папке или нет
$Path2mp3Folder = $Path2mp3Folder -replace "\\$"
#Создаем объек "оболочки" (Shell.Application)
$Shell= New-Object -COM Shell.Application
#Получаем объект с целевой папкой
$Folder=$Shell.NameSpace($Path2mp3Folder)
#В целевой папке ищем все файлы с расширением mp3, 
#результирующую коллекцию помещаем в $FolderItems
$FolderItems = dir "$Path2mp3Folder\*.mp3"
#Удаляем PlayList, если таковой уже существует
del ("$Path2mp3Folder\___"+$Folder.Title+".m3u") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Создаем пустую хэш-таблицу, в которую мы будем собирать информацию
#о расширенных свойствах файла
$mp3File=@{}
#Обрабатываем каждый файл из полученной коллекции файлов
ForEach ($Item in $FolderItems) {
    #Получаем объект, с расширенными свойствами файла
    $File                    = $Folder.ParseName($Item.Name)
    #Извлекаем расширенные свойства файла и заполняем ими хэш-таблицу
    $mp3File.Name            = $File.Name
    $mp3File.Path            = $File.Path
    #$mp3File.ArtistName    = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File,9)
    $mp3File.AlbumName        = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File,17)
    $mp3File.SongTitle        = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File,10)
    $mp3File.TrackNumber    = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File,19)
    #$mp3File|ft -AutoSize
    #Если расширенные свойства (которые мы хотим использовать) не пусты, 
    #то сформируем новое имя файла и, затем, переименуем файл
    if ((($mp3File.AlbumName -ne "") -and ($mp3File.TrackNumber -ne "")) -or ($mp3File.SongTitle -ne "")) {
        #Формируем новое имя файла
        $NewFileName=$mp3File.AlbumName + "--" + ("{0:D2}" -f [int]$mp3File.TrackNumber) + "--" + $mp3File.SongTitle  + ".mp3"
        #Удалим из нового имени файла недопустимые для имени файла символы,
        #которые, возможно, содержатся во вновь сформированном имени файла
        $NewFileName = $NewFileName -replace "[\/\\\*\?\<\>\|:`"]"
        #Заменяем пробелы на "знак подчеркивания" ("_")
        $NewFileName = $NewFileName -replace "[\s]","_"
        #Переименовываем файл
        ren $mp3File.Path $NewFileName -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue #-WhatIf
    }
    else {
        $NewFileName= $mp3File.Name
    }
    #В качестве бонуса ;) сформируем playlist
    $NewFileName | Out-File ("$Path2mp3Folder\___"+$Folder.Title+".m3u") -Append -Encoding default
}
```

Как запускать:

```
.\mp3_rename_by_tags.ps1 "C:\mp3\Vysotskiy_new_sound"
```